# Storyboard Segue settings are being lost

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, storyboard, uistoryboardsegue

Within visual studio I create a segue with <kbd>Crtl</kbd> + Click to the view controller. However when I click to change the identifier, the segue loses all settings and is set to blank. I try to change it back to show and just reverts to this again.

[image]